# Automating WhatsApp using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am made this simple whatsapp bot using python and selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

target = "Someone"
msg = "Something"

input('Press Enter after scanning QR Code...')

TargetXML = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = " 
{}"]'.format(target))
TargetXML.click()

MsgBox = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_1Plpp')


MsgBox[0].send_keys(msg)
SendButton = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_35EW6')
SendButton[0].click()
```

At first run, I had `MsgBox.send_keys(msg)` and `SendButton.click()` instead of what you see in the script which gave an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'` and `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`.

I changed them to index 0 which solved the error and the script worked perfectly fine but I couldn't really understand why it worked with the element in 0th index so I tried to print the element and got the output as `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bd86fe53729956ba1fc3b16cf841a1a8", element="0.5125252686493715-2")>` I am still not convinced with it and have that question in mind. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method 'find_elements_by_class_name' returns a list of elements that satisfy the class name in the parameter. This list consists of WebElement when you select the 0th element, you get the object of WebElement, over which you can apply the methods send_keys() and click().

For more information on Selenium and WebElement object refer to [this documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement).

Comment: Oh I get it now... Thank you!